# Child divs not taking parent height

Tags: html, css, height

I want height of children div `.cell` to take up 100% height of parent. But it is not happening.

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    header
</div>
<div class="wrapper">    
    <div class="padding">
        <div class="table bg">
            <div class="cell">
                hello world
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                dummy text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{height:100%;}
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
.footer,.header{background:black;height:30px;color:white;}
.wrapper{min-height:calc(100% - 60px);height:auto !important;}
.padding{padding:20px;}
.table{display:table;width:100%;}
.cell{display:table-cell;}
.bg{background:#ccc;}
```

I think it is not happening because I have

```
.wrapper{min-height:calc(100% - 60px);height:auto !important;}
```

It happens if I change `.wrapper` to

```
.wrapper{height:calc(100% - 60px);}
```

then it is happening.

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gdppS/8/)

Comment: is this what you mean?
http://jsfiddle.net/gdppS/3/

Comment: yes exactly but I cannot set fixed height of `.table`. It will depend on the browser size.

Comment: but if you do not set a height to the parent then the child wont have anything to grab on to...

Comment: can't it be set with percent,auto or any such property rather than fixing it with some pixels?

Comment: do you want the table to take the height of the wrapper?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Answer (score 3):

Child elements don't inherit `min-height` from parent elements.

So change `min-height:calc(100% - 30px);` ...

to `height:calc(100% - 30px);` on your wrapper and then set height:100% on child divs to inherit that height.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/gdppS/9/)**

**[FIDDLE2 (lots of content)](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/gdppS/6/)**

```
.wrapper
{
  height:calc(100% - 60px); /* <--- */
}
.padding
{
  padding:20px;
  height: 100% /* <--- */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* <--- */
}
.table
{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%; /* <--- */
}
```

Comment: thank you but this does not resolve my problem. I have updated fiddle.  I have added footer. If I user `height:calc(100% - 30px);`, footer is misplaced. thanks though.